# compression techniques for true random permutation of given integer N

Tags: compression

Is it possible to compress true random permutation using low order polynomial interpolation? If yes, how it can be achieved?

Comment: You can't compress random. If you can it's something more than random.

Comment: Can interpolation be used to achieve permutation( not random) ?

Comment: Perhaps if you write more than 2 sentences about this topic someone with the relevant experience can provide more help. What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried? When does this come up?

Comment: What does the subject mean? Are you saying a random permutation of the integers **1,2,3,...,N**?

Comment: [Hint: Software Engineering.SE... expect research before asking](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7826/31260)

Comment: @CandiedOrange, speaking generally, random data may certainly be amenable to compression.

Comment: @Steve show me how and I'll make you rich.

Comment: @CandiedOrange or less than random :)

Comment: @John Forkosh: I have read a paper where it is mentioned that interpolation can be used to compress a sequence of random integers. And I am curious to know how it is possible. I sent email to author but didn't get any response. I would appreciate for any clue.

Comment: Well having never read it I can tell you how I'd analyze it. Any random can be subjected to any compression technique. If I happen to flip all heads many techniques will be very efficient. If I don't they'll likely all be very poor. If you can find any compression technique that reliably works well on a source of random it means you either got lucky or need a better source of random.

Comment: Already answered: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2686429/compressing-random-permutation-of-n

Comment: As mentioned in that math.stackexchange answer, there are **N!** possible permutations of **1,2,3,...,N**  (each number must appear exactly once) versus **N^N** random sequences (any particular number may occur 0 or 1 or 2 or more times). And since **N!<<N^N**, random permutations are compressible compared to random sequences. But I don't offhand see how you'd use interpolation to accomplish that. **Why don't you post a link to this secret paper you keep on citing???**

Comment: @John Forkosh: the paper that I am referring is: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF02215679.pdf

Comment: Key words are in the abstract "...approximation to the data..."  Its trivially easy to compress random data if you don't mind never seeing it again.  You have mixed up compressing with discarding. If I have an orange and squeeze the juice out and let it run down the drain, did I compress the orange?  If I sold you and orange, because you wanted to make an orange drink, would you be happy with my compressed orange?

Comment: Sorry, it is not all clear to me. I need to compress the given data set of N integers. Here, I don't understand how to interpolate if all the integers in range 1-N appears exactly once. how can I interpolate to compress them? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an extended comment, too long for a comment. Firstly, the abstract in your link https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02215679 discusses "data compression", but not "random", per se. And as @CandiedOrange first mentioned, random data isn't compressible. And that's simply by definition, e.g., google "Kolmogorov complexity". If you can compress a string, it's not random -- by definition.

But as my comment mentions, permutations aren't entirely random since they're constrained by the requirement that each integer **1,2,...,N** appears exactly once. And that means **N!** possible permutations, versus **N^N>>N!** possible random sequences.

So here's one possible permutation compression strategy, though it has absolutely nothing to do with interpolation. Choose an enumeration of the permutations of **1...N**, whereby you can reconstruct a permutation by its index **1...N!** in the enumeration. And that index requires just **log_2(N!)** bits. In comparison, an enumeration of all sequences would require **log_2(N^N)** bits to specify an index, whereby random permutations are compressible compared to random sequences.

Comment: I appreciate you but my professor wants me to use interpolation to compress the data given in the range of 1-N , where each integer appears exactly once. And also I need to recover data by rounding off the result. I don't still understand the concept. coding is not a problem for me.

Comment: @user9340043 Well, yeah, I don't understand the concept, either. You have some function **f(x)** and a table of its values at some discrete points **f(x_i),i=1...n**, and some **n^th** degree polynomial that hits those points, and all that somehow participates in an algorithm to compress random permutations??? When your teacher eventually explains how that works, please edit you question (or post an answer) to explain it to us.